# Shortest cycle containing a particular edge?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Let $(u,v)$ be an edge in the graph, I have to develop an algorithm to find the length of the shortest cycle containing this particular edge.
Also, the graph has only positive edge weights

Here's what I have so far, and I wanted to know if I am in the right path (or, if this is correct):

•Remove $(u,v)$ from the graph

•Compute the length of the shortest path from $u$ to $v$ in the modified graph

•Return $shortestPathLength(u,v)+weight(u,v)$

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: The way to tell whether your algorithm is correct is to prove it correct.  You might also want to search for counterexamples, by trying it on some simple examples (or even code it up and run it on random graphs and compare its answer to that of a reference algorithm that you know is correct).